# Gettling starling to work with box2d and debugdraw with as3

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d

This topic has been raised before, but not one of the examples I've found online seem to work for me! I am trying to get starling to work with box2d, and also for the box2d debugdraw.

I have tried a bunch of different methods, and my code is now a bit of a mess due to commenting out to try different mixes of the "solution". Does anyone know how to do all this properly? I would be greatly in dept if someone could explain it.

Here is the last attempt I tried:

In my Startup class:

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
//import flash.events.Event;

import starling.core.Starling;
//import starling.display.Sprite;

import flash.events.Event;

[SWF(width="640", height="480", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#000000")]

public class Startup extends Sprite {
    public static var mStarling:Starling;
    public static var debugSprite:Sprite;


    public function Startup() {
    //addChild ( new Stats() );

    super();

    //stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    //stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

    // create our Starling instance
    mStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);

    // set anti-aliasing (higher the better quality but slower performance)
    mStarling.antiAliasing = 1;

    mStarling.showStats = true;

    // start it!
    mStarling.start();


    stage.stage3Ds[0].addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContextCreated);
    }

    private function onContextCreated(e:Event):void{
        ////debug mode
//            debugSprite=new Sprite();
//            //addChild(debugSprite);
//          Starling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(debugSprite);

        //var debugSprite:Sprite=new Sprite();
        addChild(debugSprite);
        (mStarling.stage.getChildAt(0) as Game).DebugDraw(debugSprite)

    }
```

I call the debugdraw like this:

```
debugDraw(Startup.debugSprite);
```

Here is a heavily commented out debugdraw:

```
  private function debugDraw(debugSprite:flash.display.Sprite):void {
    /*var worldDebugDraw:b2DebugDraw=new b2DebugDraw();
    //var debugSprite:flash.display.Sprite = new flash.display.Sprite();
    var debugSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    addChild(debugSprite);
    //mStarling.current.nativeOverlay.addChild(debugSprite);
    //worldDebugDraw.SetSprite(debugSprite);
//debugDraw.SetSprite(Starling.current.nativeOverlay); //DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK
            worldDebugDraw.SetDrawScale(worldScale);
            worldDebugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit|b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);

            //worldDebugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.0);
            //worldDebugDraw.SetAlpha(0.0);
            //visible
            worldDebugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.8); //for testing
            worldDebugDraw.SetAlpha(1); //for testing

            world.SetDebugDraw(worldDebugDraw);*/

            var worldDebugDraw:b2DebugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
            worldDebugDraw.SetSprite(debugSprite);
            world.SetDebugDraw(worldDebugDraw);

        }
```

Comment: Please define "work".

Comment: Presumably it does not show debug drawing.

Answer (score 0):

DebudDraw works with ONE classic Flash Sprite (you keep creating new ones for some reason). Only one b2DebugDraw should be created and set with that ONE Sprite.

Starling pretends to own the stage and all displaylist but it doesn't. Use simply your StartUp instance or even directly the stage itself without passing through Starling it will avoid some confusion.

The right way to do all this:

```
public var debugSprite:Sprite;//no static var
```

Starting what?

```
//don't start it!
mStarling.start();
```

You star something that cannot be started. At this point you are trying to create a valid Context3D so be patient. Remove that line.

Now in onContextCreated:

```
mStarling.start();//now you can start
debugSprite = new Sprite();//create your sprite
addChild(debugSprite);
var game:Game = mStarling.stage.getChildAt(0) as Game;//Game? somebody is following a tutorial ...
if(game)
{
     game.setDebug(debugSprite);//this is a new public method to create in Game
}
```

In Game in method setDebug (with one parameter Sprite):

```
var worldDebugDraw:b2DebugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
worldDebugDraw.SetSprite(myspriteparameter);
world.SetDebugDraw(worldDebugDraw);
```

That's it, don't create new Sprite, don't create new debugdraw, you are good to go that's all you need.